# Material date-time pickers and zoned time string problem

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datepicker, timezone, iso

I have a page with `@material-ui/pickers`

```
 <TimePicker .. value={value}/> /* value == 2020-12-24T13:05:10.714Z */
```

The value in the example is a zoned datetime string coming the from server.
My time zone is +2:00, Ukraine/Kiev.

The problem is that rendered time is 15:05. Is this behaviour normal when input value is zoned datetime?
I would like to see 13:05. Is this the server that provides me with incorrect datetime format or is it me misusing @meterial/pickers and @date-fns ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`2020-12-24T13:05:10.714Z` is an ISO-8601 datetime string. The suffix `Z` means that the time is in UTC (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Coordinated_Universal_Time_(UTC))). The rendered time of 15:05 in your +02:00 zone matches that.

So yes, if your server meant to specify 13:05 Kiev time, it's using the wrong format or the wrong time. It should say `2020-12-24T11:05:10.714Z` or `2020-12-24T13:05:10.714+02:00`.

Comment: Could you mark it as such please? It's the checkmark next to the answer.